# Error is Random Number Generator when initializing an Array

Tags: c, arrays, random, permutation, random-seed

I've been working on this code which generates an array of random numbers into numArray and then it shuffles it, adds it to the array and prints out the array. This is the code I've completed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SEED 7451
#define ARRAY_SIZE 25
#define LOOPS 10

void InitializeArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength);
void ShuffleArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength);
void printArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength); 

int main()
{
   //informational message
   printf("This Program creates permutations of an array of numbers/n");

   //declare numArray with ARRAY_SIZE values as int
   int numArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

   //seed the random number generator
   srandom(SEED);


   int count;
   int arrayLength= sizeof(numArray); //sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(numArray[0]);


//LOOPED 10 times, use the LOOPS variable
for (count = 0; count < LOOPS; count++){
    //call InitializeArray
    InitializeArray(numArray,arrayLength);

    //call printArray Function to print out normal Array
    printf("Initial Array: \n");
    printArray(numArray,arrayLength);

    //call ShuffleArray to create permutation
    ShuffleArray(numArray,arrayLength);

    //call printArray Function to print out the shuffled list.
    printf("Shuffled Array: \n");
    printArray(numArray,arrayLength);
}
return 0;
}

void InitializeArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength)
{
   //adds the values in ARRAY_SIZE to the numArray
   int i;
   for (i=0; i< ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
       numArray=random()%(ARRAY_SIZE+1);
}

void ShuffleArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength)
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for(j = 1; j < arrayLength; j++){
      temp=numArray[j];
      i=j-1;

     while((i >= 0) && (numArray[i] > temp)){
        numArray[i+1]=numArray[i];
        i--;
      }
     numArray[i+1]=temp;
  }
}

void printArray(int *numArray, const int arrayLength)
{
   int i; // initialize counter
   for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    printf("%d \n",numArray[i]);
}
}
```

For some reason my random number generator keeps giving me errors.

```
numArray=random()%(ARRAY_SIZE+1);
```

Gives me an error. It says there is casting error which I don't understand. Can someone help me fix the random number generator.

Comment: Should be `numArray[i]=random()%(ARRAY_SIZE+1);`?

Comment: `for (i=0; i< arrayLength;i++)
       *numArray++=random()%(ARRAY_SIZE+1);`

Comment: In addtition to the above, you will be out of bounds with the way you calculate your `arrayLength`. Besides, why calculate it since it is a constant `ARRAY_SIZE` ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all the function random() does not exist, I guess you meant rand(). The same holds for srandom() which should be srand().

`numArray=random()%(ARRAY_SIZE+1);` must be `numArray[i]=rand();`. If you want to assign integers in a certain range you could use %(i.e. range 0-10: `rand()%11`).

Your arrayLength variable is not correct yet, as sizeof(numArray) returns the size of the array in bytes. To get the number of elemts you have to divide by the size of the type: 
`int arrayLength= sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int);`

Answer (score 0):

not quite reordering members in an array but, it does a decent job on the distribution w/in the range for which you'd want to generate a random number.
if it helps you, voila:

```
// get random number within provided base + exponent
// by Goran Biljetina --> 2012

function isEmpty(value){
    return (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null);
}
var numSeq = new Array();
function add(num,seq){
    var toAdd = new Object();
     toAdd.num = num;
     toAdd.seq = seq;
     numSeq[numSeq.length] = toAdd;
}
function fillNumSeq (num,seq){
    var n;
    for(i=0;i<=seq;i++){
        n = Math.pow(num,i);
        add(n,i);
    }
}
function getRandNum(base,exp){
    if (isEmpty(base)){
        console.log("Specify value for base parameter");
    }
    if (isEmpty(exp)){
        console.log("Specify value for exponent parameter");
    }
    fillNumSeq(base,exp);
    var emax;
    var eseq;
    var nseed;
    var nspan;
    emax = (numSeq.length);
    eseq = Math.floor(Math.random()*emax)+1;
    nseed = numSeq[eseq].num;
    nspan = Math.floor((Math.random())*(Math.random()*nseed))+1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*nspan)+1;
}

console.log(getRandNum(10,20),numSeq);
//getRandNum(-10,20);
//console.log(getRandNum(-10,20),numSeq);
//console.log(numSeq);
```